# Regex replace everything after first digit including digit with another string

Tags: r, regex, string, replace, gsub

I have some strings with this pattern: `abc_def_10_cat_dog` and I want to use gsub to replace everything after `abc_def` with `_diff`. So in the end it should be `abc_def_diff`. What regex expression would I need to do this? Another way of thinking about it could be "How do I keep all the values before the first digit and then add _diff?" I am using dplyr, gsub, on R.

I know '^[^0-9]*' keeps what I want, but I'm not sure how to just keep those characters and drop the stuff afterwards. I tried using `str_extract` as well but it kept saying 'object not found'. My object is just  a list of names.

`object <- df %>% select(vars(ends_with("10_cat_dog")) %>% names()`

Answer (score 2):

You can match on a digit and any characters until you reach the end of the string, and then replace with `diff`:

```r
library(stringr)
str_replace("abc_def_10_cat_dog", "_\\d.*$", "_diff")
#> [1] "abc_def_diff"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use base R `sub` :

```
x <- 'abc_def_10_cat_dog'

sub('\\d+.*', 'diff', x)
#[1] "abc_def_diff"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `sub`

```
sub("[0-9]+.*", "diff", x)
#[1] "abc_def_diff"
```

#### data

```
x <- 'abc_def_10_cat_dog'
```